# RVM gemset forgotten immediately

Tags: rvm

I'm having a problem very similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8670065/rvm-and-osx-lion-rvm-forgets-gemsets-on-system-restart), but rather than forgetting upon reboot, rvm doesn't appear to be aware of the gemset in the first place.

I've got several gemsets created, and those directories are indeed being created and used when I `$ rvm install rails -v 3.1.1` or whatever, but `$ rvm gemset list` produces this:

```
gemsets for system (found in /Network/Servers/xxx/Volumes/ServerData/Home/yyy/.rvm/gems/system)
*
```

I can `rvm use 1.9.2@rails311`, and rvm switches to that ruby, with its associated gemset; when I run `$ rvm info`, I get what's pasted below, but `$ bundle install` throws dependency errors that make it seem as though it's not finding the gemset.

Also, I have added the user account to the rvm group, and I don't get any permissions errors upon creating the gemsets, or installing gems to them, and all gems are actually getting downloaded and stored in the proper gemsets.

```
ruby-1.9.2-p318@rails311:

  system:
    uname:       "Darwin www.yyy.zzz 11.3.0 Darwin Kernel Version 11.3.0: Thu Jan 12 18:47:41 PST 2012; root:xnu-1699.24.23~1/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64"
    bash:        "/bin/bash => GNU bash, version 3.2.48(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin11)"
    zsh:         "/bin/zsh => zsh 4.3.11 (i386-apple-darwin11.0)"

  rvm:
    version:      "rvm 1.10.3 by Wayne E. Seguin <wayneeseguin@gmail.com>, Michal Papis <mpapis@gmail.com> [https://rvm.beginrescueend.com/]"
    updated:      "1 day 2 hours 32 minutes 20 seconds ago"

  ruby:
    interpreter:  "ruby"
    version:      "1.9.2p318"
    date:         "2012-02-14"
    platform:     "x86_64-darwin11.3.0"
    patchlevel:   "2012-02-14"
    full_version: "ruby 1.9.2p318 (2012-02-14) [x86_64-darwin11.3.0]"

  homes:
    gem:          "/Network/Servers/www/Volumes/ServerData/Home/yyy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318@rails311"
    ruby:         "/Network/Servers/www/Volumes/ServerData/Home/yyy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p318"

  binaries:
    ruby:         "/Network/Servers/www/Volumes/ServerData/Home/yyy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p318/bin/ruby"
    irb:          "/Network/Servers/www/Volumes/ServerData/Home/yyy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p318/bin/irb"
    gem:          "/Network/Servers/www/Volumes/ServerData/Home/yyy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p318/bin/gem"
    rake:         "/Network/Servers/www/Volumes/ServerData/Home/yyy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318@rails311/bin/rake"

  environment:
    PATH:         "/Network/Servers/www/Volumes/ServerData/Home/yyy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318@rails311/bin:/Network/Servers/www/Volumes/ServerData/Home/yyy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318@global/bin:/Network/Servers/www/Volumes/ServerData/Home/yyy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p318/bin:/Network/Servers/www/Volumes/ServerData/Home/yyy/.rvm/bin:/Network/Servers/www/Volumes/ServerData/Home/yyy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318@rails303/bin:/Network/Servers/www/Volumes/ServerData/Home/yyy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318@rails313/bin:/Network/Servers/www/Volumes/ServerData/Home/yyy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11/bin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/opt/local/lib/postgresql84/bin"
    GEM_HOME:     "/Network/Servers/www/Volumes/ServerData/Home/yyy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318@rails311"
    GEM_PATH:     "/Network/Servers/www/Volumes/ServerData/Home/yyy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318@rails311:/Network/Servers/www/Volumes/ServerData/Home/yyy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318@global"
    MY_RUBY_HOME: "/Network/Servers/www/Volumes/ServerData/Home/yyy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p318"
    IRBRC:        "/Network/Servers/www/Volumes/ServerData/Home/yyy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p318/.irbrc"
    RUBYOPT:      ""
    gemset:       "rails311"
```

Many thanks for any insights you may have to offer.

Answer (score 0):

this looks like a known RVM issue https://github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/issues/762

I should get some time to fix it within week or two, please review the ticket and give/comment any insight you think might be important

Comment: Many thanks, appreciate the heads up. So apart from rvm being unaware of the gemset, is rvm also unaware of the actual gems?

Comment: actually all gemsets/gems should be in place, this issue only touches rvm commands to list/delete gemsets