# RVM forgets gemsets when closing terminal on OSX Lion

Tags: ruby, command-line, osx-lion, rvm, zsh

I have a similar problem to the one listed here:
[RVM and OSX Lion - RVM 'forgets' gemsets on system restart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8670065/rvm-and-osx-lion-rvm-forgets-gemsets-on-system-restart)

My RVM forgets the gemsets when I simply close the terminal. I've done `rvm use --default 1.9.3-p194@mygemset` and after closing the terminal and reopening when I do `rvm gemset list` I get

```
➜  ~  rvm gemset list

gemsets for system (found in /Users/adam/.rvm/gems/system)
   *
```

Here's additional info incase you need it:
I'm on OSX Lion, using Oh-my-zsh

```
➜  ~  rvm --version

rvm 1.14.5 (master) by Wayne E. Seguin <wayneeseguin@gmail.com>, Michal Papis <mpapis@gmail.com> [https://rvm.io/]

➜  ~  rvm info

system:

  system:
    uname:       "Darwin Adams-MacBook-Pro.local 11.4.0 Darwin Kernel Version 11.4.0: Mon Apr  9 19:32:15 PDT 2012; root:xnu-1699.26.8~1/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64"
    bash:        "/bin/bash => GNU bash, version 3.2.48(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin11)"
    zsh:         "/bin/zsh => zsh 4.3.11 (i386-apple-darwin11.0)"

  rvm:
    version:      "rvm 1.14.5 (master) by Wayne E. Seguin <wayneeseguin@gmail.com>, Michal Papis <mpapis@gmail.com> [https://rvm.io/]"
    updated:      "2 days 4 hours 42 minutes 33 seconds ago"

  homes:
    gem:          "not set"
    ruby:         "not set"

  binaries:
    ruby:         "/Users/adam/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/bin/ruby"
    irb:          "/Users/adam/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/bin/irb"
    gem:          "/Users/adam/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/bin/gem"
    rake:         "/Users/adam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@global/bin/rake"

  environment:
    PATH:         "/Users/adam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@rails32/bin:/Users/adam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@global/bin:/Users/adam/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/bin:/Users/adam/.rvm/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/X11/bin"
    GEM_HOME:     ""
    GEM_PATH:     ""
    MY_RUBY_HOME: ""
    IRBRC:        ""
    RUBYOPT:      ""
    gemset:       ""
```

Thank you

EDIT:
I just removed oh-my-zsh and rvm seems to be working properly. How can I get the two (RVM and oh-my-zsh) to play nice?

Comment: This is probably a question best asked of the RVM development team.

Answer (score 1):

you need to limit amount of the OMZ plugins loaded, basically use only those that really provide you a functionality that you are in need of, if you do not know what functionallities are provided by plugin do not install it just in case, it's usually those plugins doing something extra over what rvm already does.

As always: What the system does for you it also does to you.